# ¿Existe una función que actúe como getline para strings?

Tags: c++, string

me gustaría leer una cadena de caracteres hasta llegar a la coma y guardarlo después en otro string.

He intentado usar la función `getline`, pero hasta donde sé solo sirve con `cin` o con un fichero, pero no con un string. ¿Alguien sabría una función que pueda servir como getline pero para cadenas? El intento lo dejo abajo en el código, gracias de antemano.

```
string paciente="Juan,34,hombre";
string nombre;
getline(paciente,nombre,','); //leo hasta la primera coma e inserto Juan en la cadena paciente
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream. Estudiala y, cuando tengas una pregunta **concreta**, no dudes en formularla :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar `std::stringstream`. Esta clase no es más que un *stream* en memoria. Dado que tiene la misma interfaz que `std::cin`, puede usarse con `getline` sin problemas:

```
#include <sstream> // std::stringstream

std::stringstream ss;
ss << "Juan,34,hombre";

std::string nombre;
std::getline(ss, nombre, ',');

std::cout << nombre;
```